# Add a toolbar button to a MonoTouch.Dialog project

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I am trying to figure out how to add a button to the top Toolbar on my MonoTouch.Dialog app.  A button where the "Edit" button would usually show up.  Can't find an example anywhere online.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)setRightBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated
```

In a UIViewController you would create a UIBarButtonItem of whatever style you want and then:

```
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:myButton animated:NO];
```